# How to store offchain mutable values

Tags: storage, database, offchain-storage

Are there offchain storage options in substrate? Like a regular  mongodb- or mysql database, I don't want to use something else and just stick with something supported with substrate stack.

The only thing that I found is [LocalStorage](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_client_db/offchain/struct.LocalStorage.html) but it requires a [Database](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_client_db/trait.Database.html) and the only thing that implements that trait is [in-memory](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_database/struct.MemDb.html) database which means its not persistent storage

Answer (score 1):

You can use `use sp_io::offchain_index;` it is a persistent storage.

Check the example here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/22cca143a2c8e4a03ae770d71e94329eb518cca8/frame/merkle-mountain-range/src/mmr/storage.rs#L180-L197